# how to get value from entity with have in iterable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have code like this for getting all data from my DB

```
Iterable<ProductParameter> result = service.getAllProductParameter();
```

I need to get value from one of `productParameter` `Entity`, how to get them? if I use iterable to get all data in my DB`

I have tried using this code

```
String uuid = result.getProductParameterId; but this got error
```

Comment: How is your service implemented? Does it provide a way to get a particular record?

Answer (score 1):

You should explain more details. But

`Iterable<ProductParameter> result = service.getAllProductParameter();`

return a list of object so you need to filter or loop to get what you need.For example:

`result.forEach(x -> {System.out.println(x.getProductParameterId());});`